# A function and continuity problem (multiplying by a constant)

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I have this problem about continuity and functions the question is:

$f(x)=$\begin{cases}-1 & x>1\\
-2 & x≤1 \end{cases}

the question has 3 parts

1. Is there a constant 'a' for the function $f(a)*f(x)$ that will be continuous for $x=1$?
2. is there a constant 'b' for the function $(b+f(x))^2$ that will be continuous for every x?
3. is there a constant 'c' for the function $(1+f(x))*(f(x)+c)$ that will be continuous for every x?

my attempt for the first part

We know that $f(1)=-2$ , and for it to be continuous  we need $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+ }f(x)$$=$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1^- }f(x)$$=$$f(1)$ when we apply what we have we will get $-1=-2=-2$ which means it is not continuous   (before trying anything with the $f(a)$)

so now I tried applying $f(a)$

$\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+ }f(x)*f(a)$$=$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1^- }f(x)*f(a)$$=$$f(a)*f(x)$

after applying what we have (applying what we have about $f(x)$ (-1) for the left side of the limit and (-2) for the right side)

$\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+ }-1*f(a)$$=$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1^- }-2*f(a)$$=$$f(a)*-2$

for the last step what I did was take the 2 cases we have , for $a>1$ we get $f(a)=-2$ and for $a<1$ we get $f(a)=-1$
so lastly we get $2\ne4=4$ for when applying $f(a)=-2$ and we get $1\ne2=2$ for $f(a)=-1$ so my conclusion was that there is no such a constant but I do not know if my way or approach is even right

For the second and third part I really don't know how to even begin with, so I am asking for help and tips on how to approach these type of question and not just an answer because I seem to have a lot of them the answers are not really important but I need advice.

thanks for any tips and help on how to approach these type of questions , and sorry for the English mistakes!

Comment: Your solution for the first one is correct, but pretty messy. As an advice for the other ones you could simplify the task a lot by just calculating what $f(a)$ should be in order to make that function continuous, for example : For $f(x)\cdot f(a)$ to be continuous, lateral limits must coincide, so $$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)\cdot f(a)=-f(a)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)\cdot f(a)=-2f(a)$$ so $-f(a)=-2f(a)$, and $f(a)=0$ which never happens. For the 2 and 3 you can try doing the same, just equal both lateral limits on the expression you are given, check what should the constant be and if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion for part $1$ is correct.  I think your work is also, but I haven't checked it closely.

I'll show you how to do the second part, and leave you to attempt the third part.

If the limit exists we must have $$\lim_{x\to1^-}(b+f(x))^2=\lim_{x\to1^+}(b+f(x))^2\\
(b-2)^2=(b-1)^2\\
b=\frac32$$ and it's easy to confirm that this works.

Comment: thank you for the amazing help , just to make sure I understood right ,I got the c=2 by doing the limits on both sides like you did with the 'b'

Comment: @Adamrk Sounds like you did it correctly.